# Creating a card via Trello fails with a 400 response

Tags: trello

I have tried doing this via Chello (a .NET wrapper for the Trello API) and via Fiddler. In both cases I am getting back a 400 response with "invalid value for name".

Here is the request and response data. Please note I have changed the key, token, and idList for security reasons. Also the token does have read/write permission.

```
POST https://api.trello.com/1/cards?key=<myKey>&token=<myToken> HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: api.trello.com
Content-Length: 115

{ 
  name: "My new card name", 
  desc: "My new card description", 
  idList: "<myIdList>" 
}

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 23
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
Connection: keep-alive

invalid value for name
```

Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Despite using POST, the Trello API actually expects the values to be in the query string rather than in the POST body. Your example should be more along the lines of:

```
https://api.trello.com/1/cards?key=<myKey>&token=<myToken>&name=My+new+card+name&desc=My+new+card+description&idList=<myIdList>
```

Using the code you posted, you end up with an "invalid value for name" because it is the first parameter it checks for and does not find.

Comment: This isn't quite the issue (though it will fix the problem); the args can go in the query string or in the body, but they shouldn't be JSON-encoded.

Answer (score 4):

It looks as though you're sending a JSON object as the content of the post; is that right? If you url-encode it as simple key-value pairs in the content of the post, that should work. Apologies if I'm misreading your paste.

Comment: This is correct. Trello either expects the key value pairs in the querystring or in the post payload.

Comment: Thanks for that. Been pulling my hair out!
Couldn't see this anywhere in the API documentation. Perhaps I missed it.